# minifying js file containing routing

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-ui-router

I am minifying an angular project through gulp.This project contains index.html,css,libraries,app.js(Angular module containing routing layer+controllers) and views.

I could easily minify+concat all js files,libraries and css files into one bundle file.HTML files were also easily minified but the problem is i have routing in my app.js which render templateUrl like

```
.state('dashboard.home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard/home.html'
            })
```

Now,beacause of this routing i cannot minify+concat all html files into one.because each route renders one view with its file name while there will be only one file named bundle.html.

Here,I need a guideline about how to handle this situation.

Thanks Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [gulp-ng-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-template) for this:

gulpfile.js:

```
var ngTemplate = require('gulp-ng-template');

....

gulp.task('templates', function () {
  return gulp.src(['view1.html', 'view2.html'])
  .pipe(ngTemplate({filePath: 'js/tpl.js'}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('test'));
});
```

ngTemplate combines your views and puts them into the single file `js/tpl.js` that will look like this:

```
 angular.module('ngTemplates').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
   $templateCache.put('view1.html', '<div class="test">A</div>\n');
   $templateCache.put('view2.html', '<div class="test">\n <span>B</span>\n</div>\n');
 }]);
```

Now all you need is to include this file into your index.html. Your views will be available to the angular compiler at their original paths. You don't need to include your original `html` views into project any more.

You can add this file `js/tpl.js` to your index.html manually or by using [ng-html-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of concatenating all templates into one `html` file you should use `$templateCache` angular provider and convert all of your `html` templates into `JavaScript` code. By using `templateCache` you can put all of your teplates into one file and it will work perfectly with routing mechanism. Try this gulp module [Gulp ng templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-templates)

Comment: by doing this,will it work without including view files?

Comment: You will get `.js` file with templates as strings, and you will need only to include this file in `<script>` tag as well as your libs and `app.js` file into your `index.html`

Comment: m getting this error 'app/views/dashboard/home.html' 404 not found while this is present in templates.min.js like this       $templateCache.put("dashboard/home.html",........

Comment: you need to set proper url for template. In this case, you need to make url to your template absolute, like this `/dashboard/home.html` instead of relative variant

Comment: sorry i can't understand where to set this absolute url?in app.js routing file?

Comment: Yes, but also you need to configure `gulp ng-templates` task to produce the equivalent absolute url: in state config `.state("dashboad",{url:'/dashboard/home.html'})` and in `$templateCache`: `$templateCache.put('/dashboard/home.html',......)`